# Run Informatica workflows using Python

Tags: python, informatica-powercenter

I am in Operations and have to run workflows from informatica.
Is there any Python package through which I can automate this part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any API available, but you can achieve it via WSH calls. It's possible to use WebService calls to invoke workflows. You can use a package like [zeep](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zeep). You can read more on Informatica Webservices [here](https://marketplace.informatica.com/solutions/mapping_webservices_provider).